# Normalisation in database : Please explain the difference between them

Tags: mysql, database, oracle

So , I'm new to databases and really confused about the **normalisation in database**. 1NF 2NF 3NF and other are confusing. Can someone provide me a ***link*** or explain these terms and the difference amongst them.

If you can provide an easy way to remember these , that'd be really helpful.

Comment: @RagingBull I'm getting confused there.... I'm guessing that's why stack overflow was created ; to solve the doubts and since google is confusing me, I asked this question here.

Comment: I am sorry to say, that is not what stackoverflow is supposed to do. stackoverflow is designed to help people who seek trouble with their programs or codes when they face any specific problem. I don't think anyone will be interested in teaching something from the scratch.

Comment: I never asked anyone to teach me from scratch. I was just asking for the links. I never asked anyone to explain me (if they don't want to).

Comment: `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.` Questions related to such things are considered to be off-topic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71462/discussion-between-raging-bull-and-psychocoder).

Comment: No problem !! Next time you come to stackoverflow, ask a specific problem. We are happy to help you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalization can be viewed as a series of steps designed, one after another, to deal with ways in which tables can be “too complicated for their own good”. the purpose of normalization is to reduce the chances for anomalies to occur in a database

**Object of normalization:**
(1) contain all the data necessary for the purposes that the database is to serve.
(2) have as little redundancy as possible,
(3) accommodate multiple values for types of data that requires them,
(4) permit efficient updates of the data in the database, and
(5) avoid the danger of losing data unknowingly.

At all levels and in every case of table with a complication , the resolution of the problem turns out to be the establishment of two or more simpler tables which, as a group contain the same information as the original table, but because of their simpler individual structures, lack the complication.

***Database normalization Rule 1***: **Eliminate Repeating Groups.** Make a separate table for each set of related attributes, and give each table a primary key.

Unnormalized Data Items for Puppies
•   puppy number
•   puppy name
•   kennel code
•   kennel name
•   kennel location
•   trick ID
•   trick name
•   trick where learned
•   skill level
In the original list of data, each puppy description is followed by a list of tricks the puppy has learned. Some might know 10 tricks, some might not know any. To answer the question “Can Fifi roll over?” we need first to find Fifi’s puppy record, then scan the list of tricks associated with the record. This is awkward, inefficient, and extremely untidy.
Moving the tricks into a seperate tablehelps considerably. Seperating the repeating groupsof tricks from the puppy information results in first normal form. The puppy number in the trick table matches the primarykey in the puppy table, providing a foreign key for relating the two tables with a join operation. Now we can answer our question with a direct retrieval look to see if Fifi’s puppy number and the trick ID for “roll over” appear together in the trick table.

***First Normal Form:***
Puppy Table
puppy number                     — primary key
puppy name
kennel name
kennel location
Trick Table
puppy number
trick ID
trick name
trick where learned
skill level

***Database Normalization Rule 2***: **Eliminate Redundant Dat**a, if an attribute depends on only part of a multi-valued key, remove it to a separate table.
The trick name (e.g. “roll over”) appears redundantly for every puppy that knows it. Just trick ID whould do.

TRICK TABLE
Puppy Number Trick ID Trick Name Where Learned Skill Level
52                     27         ”roll over”             16                      9
53                    16        “Nose Stand”         9                      9
54                     27         ”roll over”              9                       5
*Note that trick name depends on only a part (the trick ID) of the multi-valued,  i.e. composite key.
In the trick table, the primary key is made up of the puppy number and trick ID. This makes sense for the “where learned” and “skill level” attributes, since they will be different for every puppy-trick combination. But the trick name depends only on the trick ID. The same name will appear redundantly every time its associated ID appears in the trick table.

***Second Normal Form***
puppy table
puppy number
puppy name
kennel code
kennel name
kennel location
tricks table
tricks ID
tricks name
Puppy-Tricks
puppy number
trick ID
trick where learned
skill level
Suppose you want to reclassify a trick, i.e. to give it a different trick ID. The change has to be made for every puppy that knows the trick. If you miss some of the changes, you will have several puppies with the same trick under different IDs, this is an update anomaly.

***Database normalization Rule 3***: **Eliminate columns not dependent on key**. If attributes do not contribute to a description of the key, remove them to a separate table.
Puppy Table
puppy number
puppy name
kennel code
kennel name
The puppy table satisfies the first normal form, since in contains no repeating groups. It satisfies the second normal form, since it does not have a multivalued key. But the key is puppy number , and the kennel name and the kennel location describe only a kennel, not a puppy. To achieve the third normal form, they must be moved into a separate table. Since they describe a kennel, kennel code becomes the key of the new “kennels” table.

**Third Normal Form**

Puppies
puppy number
puppy name
kennel code
Kennel
kennel code
kennel name
kennel location
Tricks
trick ID
trick name
Puppy Tricks
puppy number
trick ID
trick where learned
skill level
The motivation for this is the same as for the second normal form. We want to avoid update and delete anomalies. For example suppose no puppies from the Puppy Farm were currently stored in the database. With the previous design, there would be no record of its existence.

Copied From:
1) http://www.dbnormalization.com/

Usefull link:
1) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_Normalization

Comment: Please don't plagiarize

Comment: @Sathya: provided links, if you can see.

Comment: 'providing links' doesn't justify plagiarism

Comment: @Sathya Plagiarism is the "wrongful appropriation" and "stealing and publication" of another author's "language, thoughts, ideas, or expressions" and **the representation of them as one's own original work**.

Comment: @psychoCoder: Yes. On Stack Overflow, said representation takes the form of the user signature that is found at the bottom of every question and answer. Note that the user didn't say the content came from these links - he just said that the links were useful, which means they could very well be unrelated to the content and make this entire answer seem like he wrote it himself.

Comment: Suresh, please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing for help on referencing work that is not your own. Simply copying and pasting entire articles wholesale and then leaving a link or two at the end is not acceptable.